# Is there any way to disable all warnings with a pragma in clang or gcc?

Tags: gcc, warnings, clang

GCC and clang let you compile with -w to disable all warnings, but I can't see a #pragma equivalent of it. I can see only pragma support for disabling individual files.

I need this because I have code that I want to compile with high warning levels but which necessarily compiles third party code which generates arbitrary warnings.

Comment: Modifying the source seems a bit strange; why not handle this via different `Makefile` targets?

Comment: Being able to do it in the code via a pragmas allows you to disable the warnings around only the code that it needs to be disabled for instead of disabling it for the entire translation unit.  It also allows you do it conditionally by using _Pragma.

Answer (score 1):

You can *kind of* do it with GCC, almost, using `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored`, but unluckily not very well, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

The problem is that you cannot just "disable all", you have to disable each single one. Plus, for some warnings it doesn't work (and the docs don't tell you which ones...).

My guess is that this somewhat preliminary and will (hopefully) be improved in the next version.

Comment: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"` seems to work for me. Add another line for `-Wextra` if you need (because `-Wall` is _not_ all).

Comment: It doesn't work for me with gcc 9.3

Comment: I cannot get this to work for me either in g++ 11.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

For Clang, yes!

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
#endif

... your terrible code ...

#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```

There is [special handling of `-Weverything` in Clang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/5f32bcfbaeff1c5ca0f3d1f5036bcb3c20fe7a25/clang/lib/Lex/Pragma.cpp#L1352).

Unfortunately GCC does not have a similar feature. I tried `-Wall`; doesn't work. I also read the source code and couldn't see anything else that could work.